# Building with Titanium CLI for iOS Simulator and Xcode 8.0 Fails with Wrong Device IDs

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am unable to get the Titanium CLI (version 5.0.10) to work per the compatibility matrix at http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Titanium_Compatibility_Matrix-section-29004837_TitaniumCompatibilityMatrix-Node.js

When running 'sudo ti build -p ios' with my Titanium CLI set up to use Titanium SDK 5.5.1.GA and Xcode 8.0 installed, I get the following error message:

> [INFO]  Invoking xcodebuild
>   [DEBUG] Invoking: DEVELOPER_DIR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild build -target Clime -configuration Debug -scheme Clime -derivedDataPath /Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/DerivedData OBJROOT=/Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/build/Intermediates SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders SYMROOT=/Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/build/Products -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,id=3BA4641D-844F-425B-A9F3-D067DF8474FC,OS=10.0"
>   [TRACE] User defaults from command line:
>   [TRACE]     IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/DerivedData
>   [TRACE] Build settings from command line:
>   [TRACE]     OBJROOT = /Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/build/Intermediates
>   [TRACE]     SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/build/Intermediates/PrecompiledHeaders
>   [TRACE]     SYMROOT = /Users/karl/Documents/Titanium/Clime/build/iphone/build/Products
>   [ERROR] xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3BA4641D-844F-425B-A9F3-D067DF8474FC, OS:10.0 }
>   [ERROR]         The requested device could not be found because no available devices matched the request.
>   [ERROR]         Available destinations for the "Clime" scheme:
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:47A11AE8-884E-4790-A6A7-002E8F3FBE3A, OS:10.0, name:iPad Air }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EB73B5AA-8F68-4660-8172-EA98BC784772, OS:10.0, name:iPad Air 2 }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:536583C2-F7F2-4429-9FBA-90C673B03380, OS:10.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7 inch) }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:43DB3DB0-C078-4C93-B7D2-EF49D633AA78, OS:10.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9 inch) }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:407E843A-05AA-4635-BEA2-1A168E2E619A, OS:10.0, name:iPad Retina }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B136CDE2-6B0C-4A1A-967D-C198ED82A29A, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 5 }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6EABCF1D-86BC-47F5-B46E-2D06F9469051, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 5s }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:37909085-D3E7-4707-9455-BCE91AF4739E, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6 }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:90D53313-4485-417C-A64A-FE79466D019B, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:30D2AA1D-B154-4B52-9E2E-9FCE8CF7B41F, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6s }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0FC73149-2A8B-4A54-B2F8-C9993383E653, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8752BF47-F06C-4CAD-BACC-F3AFBF1F94F0, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 7 }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:18C9D798-6892-420C-A7A7-53E916C1B8B5, OS:10.0, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F392A0BD-0997-4598-9CB6-2E5D52B9A345, OS:10.0, name:iPhone SE }
>   [ERROR]         Ineligible destinations for the "Clime" scheme:
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Device }
>   [ERROR]           { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Generic iOS Simulator Device }

No matter which version of the iOS Simulator I select (iPhone 6, 6s, 7, etc) the device ID that Xcodebuild tries to build with (which matches what is actually shown for each simulator in Xcode) never matches the allowed device ID that the Titanium SDK seems to be looking for.

I don't see any glaring warnings or errors when I use 'sudo ti setup' and Check Environment. Am I missing something in my setup?

Answer (score 0):

The command I use with 5.5.1.GA
 And xcode 8:

appc run -p ios